# Ember.js Is there a way to create a custom #ID .class name instead of default ember?

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to pass in a custom class or id namespace instead of the default ember?

example: turn this

```
    <body class="ember-application">
    <div class="ember-view"></div>
    </body>
```

into:

```
    <body class="myapp-application">
    <div class="myapp-view"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

"ember-application" is hardcoded in Ember.EventDispatcher#setup, and "ember-view" is similarly a static string in the classNames property on Ember.View. Because 'classNames' is a concatenated property (which means subclasses combine their values, instead of replace them), you can add 'myapp-view' to the classNames array, but you can't remove (easily) values from super classes.

Answer (score 12):

You can pass in a **custom id**, instead of the default "ember-[numview]".

Just set the `elementId` field of the `Ember.View` Class

```
var mainView = Ember.View.create({
  tagName: "section",
  elementId: "main"
})
```

will generate:

```
<section id="main" class="ember-view">
</section>
```

To remove/modify the default className "ember-view", you need find and edit the classNames field on the PrototypeMixin on the View class...

```
Em.View.PrototypeMixin.mixins[2].properties.classNames = []

var mainView = Ember.View.create({
  tagName: "section",
  elementId: "main"
})
```

will generate:

```
<section id="main">
</section>
```

No idea about the side effects...