# emberjs add class or id to the body tag

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641123/ember-js-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-custom-id-class-name-instead-of-default-em) on how to add tags with a class to a view i.e. ::

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend
  name: 'Home',
  layoutName: 'layouts/application',
  templateName: 'views/home'
  tagName: 'div'
  elementId: 'home'
```

However, is there a way to adjust the application setup i.e. ::

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create
    Store: DS.Store.extend
        revision: 10,
        adapter: DS.fixtureAdapter
```

To configure a "class" or "id" attached to the body tag?

Current Ember Setup:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1 ember.js?body=1:3522
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 ember.js?body=1:3522
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.1 ember.js?body=1:3522
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Current source view:

```
<body class="ember-application" data-ember-extension="1">
<div id="home" class="ember-view">
<h1>Ember Layout</h1>
<h1>Home View</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

I will note I am using emblemjs for my handlebars templates and the body is setup in the application layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [add-css-classes-to-body-in-ember-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781154/add-css-classes-to-body-in-ember-js) and [jquery attr id](http://iamsteve.me/blog/entry/unique), I went with this solution:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  activate: ->
    this._super();
    document.title = Ember.get('App.var_page_default_title')
    $('body').attr id: 'view_home'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your body tag isn't being created by Ember, just put it in your html.

```
<body id='foo' class='bar'></body>
```

Additionally as of Ember Data 1.0 beta 1, you no longer create the store, you should just define adapters.  See https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

I'd just attach ember to a div inside of the body element instead of the body.

```
<body class='foo'>
  <div id='putEmberHere'></div>
</body>

App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#putEmberHere'
});
```

Comment: I updated my current response, do you have any other tips? The body tag is still getting rewritten on load.

Comment: Sure, don't attach to body, attach to an element inside of it.

Comment: I just came across this solution which gives me a bit of flexibility setting classes in the body tag.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781154/add-css-classes-to-body-in-ember-js